# Issue In AWS WAF Classic Rule while deleting IP addresses range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I have rule for ip address which block specific ip ranges. I remove one range of ip address from the AWS WAF rule and AWS console shows Success-full message: **CIDRs deleted successfully**. But after some time its show the ip range which I have already removed. How the ip range is added automatically which I removed?

Comment: Hi are you sure theres no automation? Check CloudTrail

Comment: No automation. simple waf rule (IP Range) attach to it but when i remove shows success after sometime its automatically added